# Frequency form to case form - unexpected values in table

Tags: r

I'm taking count data on voting preferences by race and entering it into a table in frequency form, then expanding out to case form and using `CrossTable` to look at adjusted residuals. Here's my script:

```
### create table in frequency form 
vnames <- c("Race", "Party", "freq")
a <- c("White","Dem", 871)
b <- c("White","Ind", 444)
c <- c("White","Rep", 873)
d <- c("Black","Dem", 302)
e <- c("Black","Ind", 80)
f <- c("Black","Rep", 43)

rtable <- rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f)
colnames(rtable) <- vnames

###check table - looks fine
head(rtable)

###expand to case form
rtablecase <- expand.dft(rtable, freq = "freq")

###check table - *here's where it gets weird*.
head(rtablecase)
```

The first two rows hold the value of `"1"` in the race column rather than `"White"`. Everything else is as expected. Why? I eventually just manually replaced the values (see below) so I could run `CrossTable` and it looks fine, but can someone please tell me where these two 1s are coming from?*

```
### replace 1s in Race column 
rtablecase[1,1] <- "White"
rtablecase[2,1] <- "White"

###convert to data frame
rtcasedf <- data.frame(rtablecase)
head(rtcasedf)

###Crosstabulation with adjusted residuals
CrossTable(rtcasedf$Race, rtcasedf$Party, format="SPSS", asresid=TRUE, chisq=TRUE)
```

Comment: `expand.dft`? `CrossTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior seems to be due to a bug in the `expand.dft` function. I created a simple function `myfun` that allows you to create a matrix similar to the one created by `expand.dft`.

```
myfun <- function(x, freq = "Freq") {
  # repeat the row indices according to `freq`
  idx <- rep(seq(nrow(x)), as.integer(x[, freq]))
  # expand matrix and ignore `freq` column
  x[idx, colnames(x) != freq]
}
```

Note that is function is not meant to replace `expand.dft` but works for simple cases only.

Try it with your data set `rtable`:

```
rtablecase <- myfun(rtable, freq = "freq")
```

The result:

```
head(rtablecase)
#   Race    Party
# a "White" "Dem"
# a "White" "Dem"
# a "White" "Dem"
# a "White" "Dem"
# a "White" "Dem"
# a "White" "Dem"
```